# How to join three tables and aggregate a column from the third table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, duplicates, aggregate

I have three tables as follows:

Table `A`:

```
id
--
1
2
```

Table `B`:

```
id   | table_a
-----+------------
100  | 1
101  | 1
102  | 2
103  | 2
```

Table `C`:

```
id   | table_b | item
-----+---------+-------
200  | 100     | Apple
201  | 100     | Apple
202  | 101     | Orange
203  | 102     | Apple
204  | 103     | Banana
205  | 103     | Rice
```

I want to get one row for every row in table `A`, with the contents of table `C` aggregated. (I guess with the `ARRAY_AGG()` function?)
Obviously, table `A` joins with table `B` which joins with table `C`. The final table will have the following contents:

```
id_table_a | item
-----------+---------------------
1          | Apple, Orange
2          | Apple, Banana, Rice
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify, but your example also suggests to:

- ... de-duplicate items per `id_table_a`.
- ... sort items by `c.id` - for practical reasons I suppose the lowest `c.id` per group of duplicates.

Assuming referential integrity, we don't need to involve table `a` at all. Cheaper.

To remove duplicates while sorting by the minimum `id` per group, use a two-step aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id_table_a
     , string_agg(c.item, ', ' ORDER BY c_id) AS items
FROM  (
   SELECT b.table_a AS id_table_a, c.item, min(c.id) AS c_id
   FROM   b
   JOIN   c ON c.table_b = b.id
   GROUP  BY b.table_a, c.item
   ) c
GROUP  BY id_table_a
ORDER  BY id_table_a;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GoNe1Hy9)

It's typically faster to sort in the subquery once instead of the per-group sort in the above query:

```sql
SELECT id_table_a
     , string_agg(c.item, ', ') AS items
FROM  (
   SELECT b.table_a AS id_table_a, c.item
   FROM   b
   JOIN   c ON c.table_b = b.id
   GROUP  BY b.table_a, c.item
   ORDER  BY b.table_a, min(c.id)
   ) c
GROUP  BY id_table_a
ORDER  BY id_table_a;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> Alternatively, supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work.